# How to send CTRL+C (SIGINT) signal to the background process in Windows

Tags: python, c, windows, process, sigint

How to send CTRL+C (SIGINT) signal to the background (without console) process in Windows?
At the moment I stop the process with the command:
`taskkill /f /pid 123`
But it's a hard shutdown.

I tried to do it in C.

```
AttachConsole(123)
SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, true);
GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT , 0);
```

But this is impossible. Process does not have a console.

In python:

```py
os.kill(123, signal.SIGINT)
```

Also it's hard shutdown.

Comment: SIGINT doesn't exist as such in Windows, Windows doesn't have signals. So if there is no console, you can't send Ctrl+C to it. If there is a window (even a hidden one) or at least the thread is pumping messages you may be able to send a message.If it's a service, you may have the service manager send a service control request. If it has a named pipe for control, you may use that, etc. It depends on what the process in question does and how it's designed to be controlled.